# Get time difference in android?

Tags: android, datetime

In my android app, i am getting date and time in following format via HTTP request.

> Tue Apr 17 16:23:33 IST 2012

Now i want to calculate the time difference between that time and current time.I have got lot of ways to calculate time difference in the internet but all those solutions are with different formats.How can i calculate time difference with above time format?

**Edit:**
This is the code i used its working fine.

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
  Date dateOne = df.parse("Tue apr 22 13:07:32 IST 2012");
  Date dateTwo = df.parse("Tue Apr 22 13:07:33 IST 2012");   
  long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
  System.out.println("difference:" + timeDiff); //differencs in ms
```

but i have to take current time in format "Tue apr 22 13:07:32 IST 2012" to use as dateTwo.

Comment: i didnt get you can explain it

Comment: I want to use current time as dateTwo.i used following code to get current time but its not working.                             String currentDate=String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date dateTwo = df.parse(currentDate);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also this code:::

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date dateOne = df.parse("2011-02-08 10:00:00 +0300");
Date dateTwo = df.parse("2011-02-08 08:00:00 +0100");   
long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
System.out.println("difference:" + timeDiff);   // difference: 0
```

Comment: thanks agrawal i tried your code it is working with my date and time format also but i have to get current date and time in above format.i have edited the question hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: try this Date dateTwo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Date pdate = /* your date comming from HTTP */
Date cdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

long difference = cdate.getTime() - pdate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)` using the pattern describing your date mentioned above.

Next use `parse(String)` and pass ure date string to it. It should return you a `Date` object.
You can then use the `Date.getDateInstance().getTime()` to get your current time.

Getting the time difference is then a matter of subtracting server time from current time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below code.

```
String format = "Tue Apr 17 16:23:33 IST 2012";
    int month = 0;

    Calendar yourDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    String[] months = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
            "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    String datArr[] = format.split(" ");

    String[] time = datArr[3].split(":");

    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        if (months[i] == datArr[1]) {
            month = i;
        }
    }

    yourDate.set(Integer.parseInt(datArr[5]), month, Integer.parseInt(datArr[2]), Integer.parseInt(time[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(time[1]));

    Log.i("Your Date= ", yourDate.toString());
    Log.i("Now Date= ",Calendar.getInstance().toString());
```

Using this you can get time difference between these two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference in time in miliseconds using this method and get the outputs in seconds, minutes, hours, days, months and years.

You can download class from here: [DateTimeDifference GitHub Link](https://github.com/batuhan15/DateTimeDifference)

- Simple to use

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long previousTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - 864000000); //10 days ago

Log.d("DateTime: ", "Difference With Second: " + AppUtility.DateTimeDifference(currentTime, previousTime, AppUtility.TimeDifference.SECOND));
Log.d("DateTime: ", "Difference With Minute: " + AppUtility.DateTimeDifference(currentTime, previousTime, AppUtility.TimeDifference.MINUTE));
```

- You can compare the example below

```
if(AppUtility.DateTimeDifference(currentTime, previousTime, AppUtility.TimeDifference.MINUTE) > 100){
    Log.d("DateTime: ", "There are more than 100 minutes difference between two dates.");
}else{
    Log.d("DateTime: ", "There are no more than 100 minutes difference between two dates.");
}
```